# How to render two types of data from controller to view in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to render the two sets of data models from mongodb to View.
This following code is an implementation of controllers.js and I would like to render the data to sensors.ejs.

```
Sensor.find({'type': 'thermometer'}).select('type value createdAt').exec(function(err, data){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('sensors', { thermosensors: data, moment: moment });
    });

Sensor.find({'type': 'hygrometer'}).select('type value createdAt').exec(function(err, data){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('sensors', { hygrosensors: data, moment: moment });
    });
```

It worked fine when I was only rendering the thermometer data but when I added the exact same line for hygrometer it did not pass through. How can I render these data separately filtered by the types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below answer:

```
const _ = require('underscore)
Sensor.find({'type': {$in : ['thermometer', 'hygrometer']}).select('type value createdAt').exec(function(err, data){
    if(err) throw err;
    let sensorData  = _.groupBy(data, 'type')
    res.render('sensors', { thermosensors: sensorData.thermometer, hygrosensors: sensorData.hygrometer moment: moment });
});
```